# Media Player Web Part - Failed to Load

Tags: media-streaming

1. Added a media webpart
2. I uploaded a mp3 and wav to a sharepoint library
3. I can play media
4. However, if I change the media source to "From Address" with the same mp3 and wav (sitting on a file share but accessed through http) then I get "Media Failed to load".

I can go to any browser and type http://myMediaServer:5555/CrewHealth.mp3 and it resolves right away. Directory browsing is enabled when i go to http://myMediaServer:5555 I can all the media files. Anonymous browsing is enabled. Everyone in the company has read access.

Comment: I just tried Expression Encoder 4 to encode one of the mp3 but same output. I am still getting "Media failed to load". It seems to me that web part is not able to connect to http location. PLEASE ANYONE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it. Forget all the mambo jambo with silverlight webpart. Can anyone suggest how to enable pause button (play, stop, forward, rewind are all present except pause).

```
<div align="center">
    <embed src="http://directlink_to_video.wmv"
        autoplay="false"
        loop="false"
        width="600"
        height="400"
    </embed>
</div>
```

Comment: If you give your embed tag an ID you can use JavaScript to target it for start/stop. A better user experience would probably to utilize an HTML5 <audio controls> tag which provides browser controls for play, pause, etc, and only fall back to JavaScript if the user doesn't have an HTML5 compatible browser.

Comment: I thought about html 5 but we are not there as enterprise level. Thanks wdes